# Doubt about Clausius Inequality

Tags: thermodynamics

In his text "[On the Application of the Theorem of the Equivalence of Transformations to Interior Work](http://www.humanthermodynamics.com/Clausius.html#anchor_156)", Clausius wrote

> If the cyclical process is not reversible, the equivalence values of the positive and negative transformations are not necessarily equal, **but they can only differ in such a way that the positive transformations predominate**.

Maybe my doubt is related to my inattention on reading the text, but which proposition he made use of in order to assert that the "net transformation" is necessarily positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Carnot's Theorem.  Maybe having the modern name will help.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)

Comment: So the fact is that, given two reservoirs, a Carnot engine has an positive amount of entropy associated with each cycle and this amount is less than the entropy per cycle of any other engine operating between the same reservoirs?

Comment: In the Carnot engine, heat (and therefore entropy) is brought in from the hot side, and a smaller amount of heat (but the exact same amount of entropy) is dumped into the cold side.  

Any other engine generates extra entropy.  So any other engine has separate "entropy in" and "entropy out" values.